# Run JUnit tests in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I created new Android Project and tried to run tests (JUnit) and had follow result:

> 15:28:53: Executing external tasks 'cleanTest test --tests com.binomv.rimidalv.tt.*'...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'TT'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Artifact 'kxml2.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0)' not found.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 0.512 secs
>   Artifact 'kxml2.jar (net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0)' not found.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar

But if i use test through device - it is ok.

Thank you.

-----UPDATE-----

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.binomv.rimidalv.tt"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```

----- **SOLUTION** -----

You should remove "~/.gradle" folder. Android Studio recreate it.

Comment: How do you try to run your tests? Via AndroidStudio or by typing "gradle test"? Do you have BuildVariant set to UnitTests?

Comment: Via AndroidStudio. Right mouse clicked to file - run - filename(junit icon). And also tried All tests. I haven't BuildVariant. It is new project. It was the first what i did.

Comment: In android studio pres Ctrl+Shift+A, start typing 'build variants', open it and switch Test Articat to 'Unit Tests'

Comment: I think i did junit test incorrect. I'll try to do it different way. Thank you.

Comment: slnowak: No. It is not help to me :( .

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide your gradle.build files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73997/discussion-between-user486312-and-slnowak).